# Issue with Implementing a Recursive Function in Python to Calculate Factorials

Tags: python, function, debugging, recursion, factorial

I am trying to implement a recursive function in Python to calculate factorials, but I am facing some issues with the code. When I input a positive integer, the function is not returning the correct factorial value. I have checked the logic and syntax, but I can't seem to identify the problem.

Here's the recursive function I implemented:

```py
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. How are you calling it?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Runs fine for me.

Comment: This is a poor application of recursion, as there is no state to be maintained, so there is little even to be learned by trying it. Iteration would be a better choice.

Comment: @user207421 `factorial()` is often the first recursive function taught, because it's one of the simplest. It may not need to be recursive, but it allows demonstrating the basic features.

Comment: Are you sure you're printing the result? `print(factorial(10))`

Comment: "When I input a positive integer, the function is not returning the correct factorial value". But there's no code shown in your question to demonstrate this supposed behaviour. Your code is correct (for values of n that are greater than or equal to zero and less than ~1,000)

Comment: Please provide the input for which you get a wrong result, and what that result is, and what you expected instead. Edit the code so you include the actual call of the function with the input that produces the problem.

Answer (score -2):

your solution seems fine, although your if statement should be:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        # recursive call to the function
        return (n * factorial(n-1))
```

but other solutions are:

1- using for loop:

```
n = 17        # n!
f = 1         # result
 
for i in range(1, n+1):
    f = f * i
 
print(f"Factorial result of {n}! is : {f}")
```

2- using math:

```
import math

n = 17        # n!

 
print(f"Factorial result of {n}! is : ", math.factorial(n))
```

Comment: Your suggested solution will not work very well for 0!

Comment: @DarkKnight factorial is only for POSITIVE numbers. that's definition.

Comment: You might want to check the validity of your comment. 0! == 1

Comment: @DarkKnight op should do it, I'm giving solution not the whole page. this is just an example assuming op knows what is factorial. otherwise, you should check for negative values, floating point, etc...

Comment: You have not provided a solution because it could produce incorrect results